# Why is rapidly clicking in Stickman Hook so effective?

Tags: stickman-hook

On the webgame [Stickman Hook](https://poki.com/en/g/stickman-hook#)  if you click rapidly (8+ cps), you can rocket yourself to the other end of the map.

It seems to be especially effective on laptop-style trackpads.

Why is this so effective?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the physics engine. Whenever you click, it gives you momentum upward so you stop. Therefore, you can rapidly gain momentum upward whenever you spam click. It can also help you turn on a dime if you need it by stopping you immediately so you can turn immediately afterward by clicking.